# How to create stretch height block with CSS

Tags: html, css

Please, can someone help me with CSS (without JavaScript)?

The main block can be any fixed or not fixed (percent of it's parent) height, it's not window height.

```
<div class="main" style="height: 1337px;">

  <div class="foo">
    This block should be displayed as usual
    (not fixed height)
  </div>

  <div class="bar">
    This block should be full height
    (bar = main - foo - foo)
    independently of this content
  </div>

  <div class="foo">
    This block should be displayed as usual
    (not fixed height)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want `.main` to fill up all the 1337 pixels that aren't filled by the `.foo` divs? If so, perhaps you could edit your title or questio to be more descriptive about what your interested inn?

Comment: Instead of style="height: 1337px;" use only like this "%" form style="height:100%;".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `display: table` and `display: table-row`. <del>I think IE7/8 don't have support for this though.</del>

Update: according to [can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) IE8 has support for it so it should be fairly safe to use.

http://jsfiddle.net/XyHyg/2/

The other choice is probably [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) but AFAIK it's still in draft state and browser support still isn't so great.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

```
<div class="main" style="height: 1337px;">

  <div class="foo" style="min-height:30%; border:thin black solid">
    This block should be displayed as usual
    (not fixed height)
  </div>

  <div class="bar" style="min-height:40%;border:thin black solid">
    This block should be full height
    (bar = main - foo - foo)
    independently of this content
  </div>

  <div class="foo" style="min-height:30%; border:thin black solid">
    This block should be displayed as usual
    (not fixed height)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: vishalkin, sorry, but no. There is no opportunity to set real height for "foo" containers, because it depends of those content (which can be empty also). And foo+bar+foo must be equals main anyway (foo+foo <= main)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly all you have to do is:

```
.bar{
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xeu5/1/

Comment: In this case the height of "bar" is the same of "main".

Answer (score 0):

Define the min-height for bar and remove height from main. 
I guess you want something like this

html:

```
<div class="main">

  <div class="foo">
    This block should be displayed as usual
    (not fixed height)
  </div>

  <div class="bar">
    This block should be full height
    (bar = main - foo - foo)
    independently of this content
  </div>

  <div class="foo">
    This block should be displayed as usual
    (not fixed height)
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main{
       border:1px solid #000;
        position:relative;
    }
    .foo{
        background:#0000ff;
    }
    .bar{
        background:#00ff00;
        min-height:500px;
    }
```

working code:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xeu5/3/)